# exclude some topics from rosbag play

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file with a bunch of topics inside of it, is it possible to *exclude* some topics from being played back?

For example, the bag file might have:

```
topics:      /camera/depth/image            150 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image          
             /camera/rgb/image_color        150 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image          
             /joint_states                 2500 msgs    : sensor_msgs/JointState     
             /rosout                         35 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log          
             /rosout_agg                     35 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log          
             /tf                           7697 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage
```

And I might be interested in playing back everything **except** the `/tf` topic.

Is there a shorter way than `rosbag play file.bag --topics <topic>` with all topics?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228676/exclude-some-topics-from-rosbag-play/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-03-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't mind having to create a new bag, then perhaps you could use the [filter](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#filter) command.

To end up with a new bag file that excludes the `/tf` topic would be something like:

```
$ rosbag filter file.bag file-no-tf.bag "topic != '/tf'"
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-01-05**:
On my system this is taking about 10 minutes per gigabyte, also the bags were 10 minutes in duration- I'm not sure if that is a coincidence.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2022-03-16**:
Thanks for the answer. How do we filter several topics?

**Comment by [labude](https://answers.ros.org/users/103641/labude/) on 2022-10-28**:
Have a look at this question:
https://answers.ros.org/question/191003/can-rosbag-filter-create-a-new-bag-file-with-multiple-topics-within-it/
You can use `"topic != 'topic1' and topic != 'topic2' and ... "`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't mind the potential wastefulness, I believe you can get the effect you want by remapping the offending topic to an unused name, like this

```
rosbag play my_bag.bag /tf:=/tf_dev_null
```

I'm fairly new to ROS, but I believe this won't even cause wasted message bandwidth unless something in the system subscribes to it under its new name.

---

Originally posted by [Jay Gowdy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31410/jay-gowdy/) with karma: 136 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2017-08-02**:
Yepp, can confirm this works out..